# Graphene mutation defined as null despite returned value is NonNull

Tags: reactjs, django, typescript, graphql, graphene-django

I'm working with graphene to handle mutations on an application with django as backend. I wrote the following mutation:

```
import graphene
from django.db import transaction
from graphql_jwt.decorators import login_required

from app1.enums import SomeOptions
from app1.models import SomeModel
from app2.utils.some_api import SomeApi

class SetOtherAppConfig(graphene.Mutation):

    url = graphene.NonNull(graphene.String)

    @login_required
    @transaction.atomic
    def mutate(self, info, *args, **kwargs):
        authorization_url = SomeApi().authorization_url
        user_id = int(info.context.session['_auth_user_id'])
        company_id = int(info.context.session['id_emp'])
        SomeModel.objects.get_or_create(
            company_id=company_id,
            code=SomeOptions.API.name,
            defaults={
                'name': SomeOptions.API.value,
                'username': '',
                'password': '',
                'token': '',
                'base_url': '',
                'others': '',
                'created_by_id': user_id,
                'updated_by_id': user_id,
            },
        )
        return SetOtherAppConfig(url=authorization_url)
```

The problem is that the mutation itself its being reported as null or string. The attribute url on the other hand can only be String as expected. How can I tell graphene that the mutation (or the class) can not be null?

Comment: Why are you define `SetOtherAppConfig` mutation but returns `SetSomeConfig` class instead of `SetOtherAppConfig`?

Comment: Typo when I posted the question. The original code had other names but I had to change it to keep confidentiality.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```py
url = graphene.String(required=True)
```

Comment: Already tried, but it didn't work